# How to expose the current git tag to electron-builder on windows using azure-pipelines?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, electron-builder

My windows-fu has gone weak over the last decade and I'm quite new to azure-pipelines.

The electron-builder expects to see a git tag in the environment variable `CI_BUILD_TAG` (or several other environment variables) before performing the publish step.

On Mac and Linux the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576594/681520 works perfectly fine:

```
steps:
    - script: CI_BUILD_TAG=`git describe --tags` && echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CI_BUILD_TAG]$CI_BUILD_TAG"
      displayName: Set the tag name as an environment variable
```

How do I do this for the Windows build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $CI_BUILD_TAG = git describe --tags
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CI_BUILD_TAG]$CI_BUILD_TAG"
  displayName: 'Set the tag name as an environment variable'
```

Comment: And it indeed does. Thanks.

Comment: I think this needs to be: `Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=CI_BUILD_TAG;]$CI_BUILD_TAG")` for this to work on azure

Comment: @KimmoLehto Are you sure? I always use like I wrote without issues.