# How to generate a syso-file for Go in a windows pipline on Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, go, azure-devops, sysobjects

I want to use a syso-file by `go build` to set an icon for my executable.

Everything works fine on my win10 notebook, but when I use the same syso-file (checked in with git lfs) with ubuntu-latest or windows-latest I get this message:

```
C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build430615882\b001\_pkg_.a(rsrc.syso): not an object file

##[error]The Go task failed with an error: Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.14.2\x64\bin\go.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

When I try to recreate the syso-file I get this message: `bad magic number` when call the executable `($env:GOPATH+"\bin\rsrc.exe")` in the pipeline.

To my question, how to generate a syso-file for Go in a windows pipline on Azure DevOps and use it with `go build`?

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)/bin'
  GOPATH: '$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/gopath'
  ExecutableName: tool
  GoFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cmd/Tool/'

steps:
- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.14.2'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'get'
    arguments: '-d ./...'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set last tag to variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $VERSION_TAG = git describe --tags (git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
      Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=VERSION_TAG]$VERSION_TAG")
      Write-Host("##vso[build.addbuildtag]$VERSION_TAG")
      Write-Host($VERSION_TAG)

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set date to variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $DATE = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
      Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATE]$DATE")

- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Create release for windows x64'
  enabled: true
  env: 
    GOOS: windows
    GOARCH: amd64
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(VERSION_TAG) -X main.BuildTime=$(DATE)" -trimpath -o release_build/$(ExecutableName).exe $(GoFilePath)'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'


- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Create release for windows x86'
  enabled: true
  env: 
    GOOS: windows
    GOARCH: 386
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(VERSION_TAG) -X main.BuildTime=$(DATE)" -trimpath -o release_build/$(ExecutableName)_x86.exe $(GoFilePath)'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Create release for linux x64'
  enabled: true
  env: 
    GOOS: linux
    GOARCH: amd64
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(VERSION_TAG) -X main.BuildTime=$(DATE)" -trimpath -o release_build/$(ExecutableName).bin $(GoFilePath)'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'    


- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Create release for linux x86'
  enabled: true
  env: 
    GOOS: linux
    GOARCH: 386
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(VERSION_TAG) -X main.BuildTime=$(DATE)" -trimpath -o release_build/$(ExecutableName)_386.bin $(GoFilePath)'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'    


- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Create release for macOS x64'
  enabled: true
  env: 
    GOOS: darwin
    GOARCH: amd64
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '-ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(VERSION_TAG) -X main.BuildTime=$(DATE)" -trimpath -o release_build/$(ExecutableName).app $(GoFilePath)'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'    

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/release_build'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/docs'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'Tool Executables'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing the question I figure out, that I use `git lfs` for theses files.
After adding this step I could compile the executable with the resource file.

```
steps:

- checkout: self
  lfs: true
```

But after the build targeting GOOS windows I must delete these files, because otherwise I got the error:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.2/x64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1


/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/tmp/go-link-782633042/000000.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Step to delete these files:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Remove syso files
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Remove-Item $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cmd/AnalyseTool/*.syso
```

#### Explanation

This is a example of a v1 text pointer:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4d7a214614ab2935c943f9e0ff69d22eadbb8f32b1258daaa5e2ca24d17e2393
size 12345
(ending \n)
```

Source: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md

When the source code is downloaded **without lfs support** this text file is placed instead of the *real* file.

So it is clear, that this file cannot be executed (bad magic number) or that referenced bin files have the wrong format (not an object file).